# FXML can't see new methods

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm developing a gui for a college work and i'm using JavaFX and FXML, everything was fine until the fxml get angry.

The fxml file does not see the new methods of my controller class anymore. Yesterday, when i stopped, it was 5 methods, today i'm trying to add more methods but the fxml does not see these new methods. The scene builder doesn't show them either, only the older ones.

And the funniest part is: This only occurs with this FXML file and its controller. Others FXML files and its controllers works perfectly.

Any help?

Comment: Did you remember to annotate the methods with @FXML?

Comment: Yes i did. I also, for testing, commented some old methods and the scene builder still showing them and the FXML still accepting them.

Comment: Solved.
The problem was that in some way there was two class files with the same name and i were edditing the wrong one, my mistake.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: IMO you can safely delete this question.